# Pivot_tables' representation of DatetimeIndex is faulty

Tags: python-3.x, pivot-table, python-datetime

I am encountering this weird 'visual' effect that takes place on my pivot table.

This code outputs the representation of the `pivot_table`'s index as shown in Annex 1:

```
pt = df_sorted.pivot_table(index = [date_col],values=[measure],columns=[apporteur_col],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0)
pt=pt.loc[:,'len'].loc[:,measure][['A','B','C']]
```

While this code outputs the representation of the `pivot_table`'s index as shown in Annex 2:

```
pt = df_sorted.pivot_table(index = [date_col],values=[measure],columns=[apporteur_col],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0,margins=True)
pt=pt.loc[:,'len'].loc[:,measure][['A','B','C',"All"]]
```

As you can see, the only difference is the use of `margins=True` and the column `All`.

**My goal**

To have the representation of the index as date only. (Like Annex 1)

**My questions**

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I fix it?

**EDIT**
Even though Annex 1 shows the index as `dd/mm/yyyy` only, once I plot the `pivot_table` on a 7 days period, the x axis is shown as `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS`. (View Annex 3)
P.S : I removed the keys so the sensitive info doesn't show.

**Annex**

1. [image: Index without HH:MM:SS]
2. [image: Index with HH:MM:SS]
3. [image: Plot for the code 1]